# AJAX request doesn't get immediate response at second request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a weird problem on my web application. For the first time I do the request, it works fine, but second time onwards, I will not receive any of the return data from AJAX. But in fact, it does return data when I inspect element in "Network" tab by using Google Chrome.

And if I do the third time request, the second time request return data will appear, and third time request will not return any data until I do the fourth time request.

Here is my code...

```
$.ajax({            
            cache: false,
            url: 'the request url',
            type: 'POST',               
            data: {ad_id: $(this).children('a').attr('id')},                
            error: function(){ 
                alert('something wrong?');
            },
            success: function(response){
                $('li#tmpAjaxLoader').fadeOut(function(){
                    console.log( response );
                    if( response.indexOf('inserted') != -1 ){
                        $(this).prev('li').fadeIn(function(){
                            $(this).children('a').children('img').attr('src', '". $this->imagesPath ."/btn-favourited.png');
                            $(this).next('li#tmpAjaxLoader').remove();
                        });
                    } else if( response.indexOf('deleted') != -1 ){
                        $(this).prev('li').fadeIn(function(){
                            $(this).children('a').children('img').attr('src', '". $this->imagesPath ."/btn-favourite.png');
                            $(this).next('li#tmpAjaxLoader').remove();
                        });
                    } else{
                        $(this).prev('li').fadeIn(function(){                                       
                            $(this).next('li#tmpAjaxLoader').remove();
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Everything is in the callback for fadeOut...is that element visible and valid after the first time?

Comment: How are you calling this code?  Looking at the isolated Ajax call doesn't tell me much...

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for the reply, by the way it works for the first time, but during the second time AJAX doesn't return the data after I request it. Only until the third time I do AJAX request again, and the second time request data will return.

But from the "Network" it actually already return the data

Comment: Just click on a <li> tag link man... guess the problem is occur at this part...

Comment: By the way, thanks Matt, guess is the AJAX loader cause the problem

Comment: Comment all of the code inside of the "success" part, except for "console.log( response );". See if the correct response stuff is being logged to the console.

Comment: Yeah, the problem may be that the data is being returned but nothing is happening everything is done in a callback that is no longer being called.